# There is only a single wire going in and coming out of an opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

I was looking forward to make a pulse shaping circuit, and specifically I need to make a CR-RC shaping network (see figure attached). I see that there is an opamp but there is only one connection going in, and no feedback resistor too. Is it correct to assume that the input wire is connected to the non-inverting input and the inverting input is grounded?
[image]

(Image source: [https://ns.ph.liv.ac.uk/~ajb/ukgs_nis/pre-course-material/lec2-03.pdf](https://ns.ph.liv.ac.uk/%7Eajb/ukgs_nis/pre-course-material/lec2-03.pdf))

Comment: It is just a buffer, e.g., a voltage follower.

Comment: It takes some experience but sometimes some "components" in a schematic are just representing "functional blocks" rather than actual components.

Comment: This manuscript shows a complete pulse shaping circuit, including before and after pulse shape measurements.  It might be easier to follow.   https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03207  The authors have also published various other example circuits you might find useful.

Comment: Rather than connected to ground, it is implied that the inverting input is shorted to the output.

Answer (score 11):

At first I thought that you were mistaken and that the device was a logic buffer. I read the PDF and you're right - it says op-amp. The triangle symbol is just a higher level symbol for an amplifier.

[image]

*Figure 1. An op-amp voltage follower.*

Use an op-amp voltage follower. The idea is that it will prevent the two halves of the circuit interfering with each other.

Comment: "with each other" - The left side is supposed to interfere with the right side, isn't it?

Comment: @AndreKR I wouldn't call that interfering. `prevent (a process or activity) from continuing or being carried out properly.` It's clearly desired that `V_out` follows `V_in`...